# How to check if a user is registered from Facebook Auth token?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, oauth

I am new in `Facebook` oauth and have some confusion regarding `Auth token`. Let's take a scenario:

User logged in Android app using Facebook Oauth.
Facebook SDK generates a new `auth token`.
Fetch the data from `token` and save into database.
User logged in from different phone with same facebook account.

Now my questions are:

1) How to check whether the user is registered or not because I will get the new  `Auth token`?

2) Whenever the token will expire It will ask for login in App?

3) Is auth token and access token are same thing?

Answer (score 0):

facebook returns the same auth token even if the user registers from multiple devices. Once an auth token is obtained, you can query to facebook from any device with that auth token. 
You need to check programatically if the auth token is about to expire and refresh the access token so that the validy of the access token gets extended. Please note that the auth token gets extended only if there is a chance for extending. If the authtoken has already expired you need to make the user login again. You can use the following method to refresh the token

```
refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync()
```

You can find more details on access token in facebook developers page
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessTokenTracker/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending